# Bypassing certificate transparency with Frida

Tags: android, frida

As part of some school research I'm experimenting with Frida to see what can be done to bypass SSLpinning.

As I was hooking some methods of an application that throw SSLPeerUnverifiedException I logged the error argument saying: Certificate transparency failed.

I tried to inform myself about certificate transparency and concluded that the error was raised because my proxy-certificate that I was using was not found in the transparency log.

Is this assumption correct and is this also something that can be bypassed using Frida?

Comment: Check the source code of https://github.com/sensepost/objection it contains several anit-pining hooks.

Answer (score 1):

It can be patched by hooking the right function of your app which checks these peers with Frida. You then always return true and you will have disabled certificate transparency